# Laravel 5 Blade Not Working on CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

> I tried to install a fresh laravel project on CentOS 7 running
>   Apache/PHP 5.6/MariaDB.

on `/var/www` :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel devil
chmod -R 777 devil/storage
chmod -R 777 devil/vendor
```

> When I tried to access it from browser, it seems the blade extension
>   is not working. It keep showing blank page without any error.

I checked the HTTP response showing 500 (Internal server error) on my chrome web developer extension.

The app only work if I don't use blade templating at all (not use .blade.php extension and the blade syntax).

Below is the folder structure

```
drwxr-xr-x. 10 adzar adzar   4096 Mar 25 04:06 app
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 adzar adzar   1635 Mar 25 04:06 artisan
drwxr-xr-x.  2 adzar adzar     39 Mar 25 04:06 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    788 Mar 25 04:06 composer.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar 100509 Mar 25 04:06 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x.  2 adzar adzar   4096 Mar 25 04:06 config
drwxr-xr-x.  4 adzar adzar     52 Mar 25 04:06 database
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    503 Mar 25 04:06 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar     98 Mar 25 04:06 package.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar     87 Mar 25 04:06 phpspec.yml
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    777 Mar 25 04:06 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x.  4 adzar adzar     95 Mar 25 04:06 public
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar   1724 Mar 25 04:06 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x.  5 adzar adzar     42 Mar 25 04:06 resources
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    560 Mar 25 04:06 server.php
drwxrwxrwx.  5 adzar adzar     60 Mar 25 04:06 storage
drwxr-xr-x.  2 adzar adzar     47 Mar 25 04:06 tests
drwxrwxrwx. 26 adzar adzar   4096 Apr  8 18:31 vendor
```

The `.env file` (unchanged)

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=EOvUHTpMtavKDMx1GdkREtbves8PVEUb

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
```

I use IP address `(100.255.XXX.XXX)` to access my app using apache virtual host. Below is my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

```
...

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName 100.255.XXX.XXX

...

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 100.255.XXX.XXX
        DocumentRoot /var/www/devil/public

        <Directory /var/www/devil>
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: `The HTTP response is 500 (Internal server error) as showed on my chrome web developer extension.` Well this bit is kind of important :) Click on the request itself and check the response contents. If there's nothing there, you might have error display disabled - check the server logs. Also, make sure that you've set `$debug` to `false` in the app.php config file matching your environment.

Comment: There is nothing on the response content. The APP_DEBUG on .env file is true by default. Set it to true didn't change anything.  I checked the logs on storage/logs folder but there are no log files.

Comment: Okay, try the webserver logs, for example if it's Apache 2 they're usually at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. Note that these paths may be different for you, depending on server and OS version, virtual host configuration and so on.

Comment: Here is the entry from error_log : `[Wed Apr 08 17:24:13.572620 2015] [:error] [pid 5034] [client 36.72.194.83:60849] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/devil/s$*`

Comment: And from access_log `36.72.194.83 - - [08/Apr/2015:17:24:13 +0700] "GET /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 500 - $`

Comment: The error log is incomplete, although it appears to be hinting at the reason. Read the whole error message and try to figure out where it happens, or post the full error on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and link it here

Comment: I'm sorry. Here are the logs : [error-logs](http://pastebin.com/ujXJ7707) and [access-logs](http://pastebin.com/M7tfrzgi)

Comment: There we go: `the stream or file "/var/www/devil/storage/logs/laravel-2015-04-08.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied'`. Your document root is not writable by the server, a quick fix would be `chmod 664 /var/www/devil -r`

Comment: Still not working. It turned my app to forbidden. Even if I set the folders permission to 777, still the blade is not working.

Comment: 666 the number of the beast!! :P

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

After hours of trying I finally able to fix the problem by disabling SELinux.

```
setenforce 0
```

However, I still have no idea why.

Comment: Dude. This worked. This definitely worked. Damn. 6 hours trying to get things work, modifying apache conf, restarting the server and nothing. THIS did it. Thanks! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Blade templating caches its templates in the file system extensively.

Therefore, you need to make sure that the appropriate folders are writable by your web server.

> Laravel may require some permissions to be configured: folders within `storage` and `vendor` require write access by the web server.

Fix your folder permissions by running the following command in console:

`chmod 664 /var/www/devil/storage -R`

`chmod 664 /var/www/devil/vendor -R`

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#configuration

Comment: Still not working. I even tried to reinstall my laravel from scratch as follows:

1. `composer create-project laravel/laravel /var/www/devil`
2. `chmod 664 /var/www/devil/storage -R`
3. `chmod 664 /var/www/devil/vendor -R`

Still the blade is not working.

Comment: For your case, your storage folder will be at `/var/www/devil/laravel/app/storage`.

Comment: Nope. I am using laravel 5. The vendor and storage folder is on `/var/www/devil/storage` and `/var/www/devil/vendor`.

Comment: Can you dump your error log found in `app/storage/logs` at pastebin.com?

Comment: The problem is the app cannot write into `app/storage/logs` tough I have set the folder permission. Here is log from apache http://pastebin.com/eh3MC1D7

Comment: Also, make sure that your `storage` folder is owned by the centOS user running the `apache` process on your machine.

Comment: How do i know which user running the apache process? I tried `ps aux | grep httpd`. The result is http://pastebin.com/GHESY70R. Then I run `chown -R apache:apache devil`, still not work. I'm getting sick of this problem.